# dompdf table cell overlapping

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem in page breaking in dompdf i just want my table didnt cut when i open it as pdf in google chrome

this is my code in html guys i hope yu can help me out

```
<textarea class='tinymce' id='texteditor' name='activities'>
    <div style="position:absolute; page-break-after:always; page-break-inside:always;">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody style="vertical-align: top;">
    <tr style="height:50px;">
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" width="240">
    ACTIVITIES
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" width="250">
    TARGET OUTPUT
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" width="143">
    INPUTS
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" width="120">
    <p>BUDGET</p>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" width="177">
    ACCOMPLISHMENT
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</textarea>
```

when my cell is overlapping it cut in printing view

[This is the picture of viewing tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZAyV.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you know the answer for your question?